# A word for liking things related to a time you did not live in

Tags: meaning

Whats a word for liking things related to a time you did not live in?

For example: Liking things like Vaporwave, because of the 90's aesthetic, but have never lived in that era.

Comment: The condition might possibly be described as *anachronistic nostalgia*.

Comment: There are several words that show one's fondness of old things (including "retrophile"---a neat colloquialism I keep hearing), but I cannot think of an accepted word that would only exclude the time you have lived in.  Check out the English Language & Usage post: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79332/whats-a-word-for-a-person-who-loves-old-or-ancient-things.

Comment: @m_a_s  I think *retrophilia* works perfectly for things like Vaporwave

Comment: @m_a_s, I threw up an answer, but I like yours better.  Make it an answer and I'll upvote it.

Comment: @JBH  Ok! Will do.

Answer (score 1):

What about "retrophile" or "retrophilia".  [(Wiktionary entry for "retrophile")](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/retrophile) [(Wiktionary entry for "retrophilia")](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/retrophilia)

Answer (score 0):

*Vaporware...* that takes me back...

Offhand, I can't think of a word that specifically includes or excludes a time @m_a_s' "retrophile" isn't bad, but it's a new word meaning, "a person who likes old things" in the same manner that "anglophile" means "a person who likes England."  It doesn't really describe the liking of old things, but the person who likes old things.  A bit technical.

If you're looking for something a little less technical, try [affinity](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affinity).

> I have an affinity for vaporware, don't ask me why.